# How can I find a place in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

This is my code for searching a locatio on Google map.The app works fine but the problem is I just can find the street but I can't find the place such as KFC,Starbuck,Walmart.....Please show me how can I do that.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener,LocationListener {
GoogleMap googleMap; 
MarkerOptions markerOptions;
LatLng latLng; 
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_location);
    autoCompleteTextView.requestFocus();
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item_autocomplete));



        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting a reference to the map
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        // Getting reference to btn_find of the layout activity_main
        Button btn_find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);

        Button searchplaces=(Button) findViewById(R.id.searchplaces);

        Button howitwork=(Button) findViewById(R.id.howitwork);

        // Defining button click event listener for the find button
        OnClickListener findClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Getting reference to EditText to get the user input location
                // Getting user input location
                String searchlocation = autoCompleteTextView.getText().toString();

                if (searchlocation != null && !searchlocation.equals("")) {
                    new GeocoderTask().execute(searchlocation);
                }
            }
        };

        // Set button click event listener for the find button
        btn_find.setOnClickListener(findClickListener);


// An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
public class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
        // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Address> addresses) {

        if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
        // Adding Markers on MainActivity Map for each matching address
        for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {
            Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

            // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in MainActivity Map
            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),
                    address.getLongitude());


            // Locate the first location
            if (i == 0)
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        latLng, 14));
        }}

    }

}
```

And here is PlaceAdapter class

```
public class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<String> resultList;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExampleApp";

    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyA5ipjFYgrW85dNp4MuA-FYzI2de3frHfk";
    public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the "types" parameter which defines the Cafes or restaurants you want to include in your autocomplete search results. Please have a look at this [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/) and you will have a better idea of how to implement that in the code. All the String types will be separated by pipe which will be a part of the doInBackground() method that will be responsible for fetching out the result via http calls from Google servers. I am attaching a piece of code you can refer to the example in the link.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // creating Places class object
        googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();

        try {
            // Separeate your place types by PIPE symbol "|"
            // If you want all types places make it as null
            // Check list of types supported by google
            // 
            String types = "cafe|restaurant"; // Listing places only cafes, restaurants

            // Radius in meters - increase this value if you don't find any places
            double radius = 1000; // 1000 meters 

            // get nearest places
            nearPlaces = googlePlaces.search(gps.getLatitude(),
                    gps.getLongitude(), radius, types);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Hope this would help!!